# When "p4 copy -f" helps a lot?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

The [manual](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_copy.html) says that **-f** means

> Force the creation of extra revisions in order to explicitly record that files have been copied. Deleted source files are copied if they
> do not exist in the target, and files that are already identical are
> copied if they are not connected by existing integration records.

Honestly, I don't quite understand when **p4 copy -f** can be very useful.
Could someone please show me some simple examples of the use cases of **p4 copy -f**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve never encountered a situation where `p4 copy -f` seems like it might be useful, count yourself lucky and forget about it; there are a number of options in Perforce that are only ever useful if you’ve already dug yourself a hole and are determined to keep digging, and this is one of them.

That said, the classic case is:

1. Add `foo` in A.
2. Branch A to B.
3. Delete `foo` in B.
4. Branch B to C.
5. Merge C to A.

If `foo` never existed in C, it will not be included in a merge from C, so the change from step 3 is “lost” during the merge in step 5.  Using `p4 copy -f` in step 4 prevents this by creating a dummy file in C that can propagate the delete to A.

Note that reparenting branches like this (going from A to B to C to A, rather than going from A to B to A) is not typically recommended as a best practice because it makes merging much more complicated in general.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the example you show, indeed 5. will show "all revision(s) already integrated." But, I only need "p4 copy" from C to A, no need to add "-f".

Comment: Yes, although most of the time when changes have happened in all branches you want to `merge`, not `copy`.